VerticalGridSupportFragment Focus can't auto next down to the next row when the next ro not full
In VerticalGridSupportFragment, If I have 5 columns and number of items are 13, If the last item from the second row is selected, then on d-pad down click, Focus should go in the 3rd row. How to do it?
enter image description here
I try in CustomGridGridPresenter add the gridView.setOnKeyListener but it not work after d-pad down click.
